# Why are JPG files invisible in Georeferencer?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, jpg

I want to georeference a jpg file (map) with QGIS 1.8.0 on a Windows 7 (64 bit) machine.

The georeference window opens, but the map is not visible.
When converting the jpg file into a tif file (e.g. with gimp) everything works.
I tried it with several files. Always the same: The tif files are visible and can easily be georeferenced, while the jpg-files are not visible in the georeference window.

Any ideas?

Thanks for answers,
Ulli

Comment: Can you check in GIMP if the jpg is a jpeg2000, or has a special compression method?

Answer (score 8):

When you save your JPEG in GIMP, expand the 'Advanced Options' when the 'Export as JPEG' dialog box comes up. Un-check the 'Progressive' box and then click 'Export'.  Your JPEG is then readable in QGIS.

"Progressive" changes the encoding to display the image at increasingly higher quality levels until the image is fully loaded.  QGIS is expecting standard encoding.  Progressive encoding appears to be on by default in GIMP (at least in GIMP 2 - I can't remember for earlier versions).

Comment: It works after unchecking the "progressive" box in the export-dialog of GIMP. I expected the problem to be in QGIS and not in GIMP...Many thanks, Ulli