# How to make a polygon on QGIS based on a PDF image?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, pdf

I'm trying to take an image out of a PDF and make a shapefile on QGIS. How can I do that?

Comment: What are your efforts and what have you tried by so far? Have you seen this thread [import PDF to QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68840/import-pdf-to-qgis)?

Comment: Can you share the PDF? Sometimes Q can extract the layers of a PDF directly as vectors, depending on how the PDF was created.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import PDF to QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68840/import-pdf-to-qgis)